# Groovy configuration for logback based on hostname

Tags: groovy, logback

I am trying to configure LogBack dynamically using the hostname to setup a specific property for a logger.
I initialize a map like the following, before any appender:

```
def HOSTNAME="${hostname}"

def logEntriesTokens = [ "Info03": "myToken" ]
```

And then  I do the following:

```
appender("LogEntriesAppender",LogentriesAppender){
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{dd MMM yyyy ; HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    }
    token = logEntriesTokens[HOSTNAME]
    println HOSTNAME
    println logEntriesToken
    println logEntriesTokens[HOSTNAME]
    println token
    Ssl = false
    facility = "USER"
    filter(ThresholdFilter){
        level = ERROR
    }

}
```

And the result is the following:

```
Info03
[Info03:myToken]
myToken
null
```

For some reason, the token property is not set (I can see that from investigating the appenders hierarchy in Java). If instead I put a constant , such as token = "myToken", everything works fine. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hello Have you been able to get any solution? I am having the same issue with getting the hostname